# Store the signed version docusign in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I have written the code to the send the envelope but i need to store the signed version in salesforce record.

```
public class SendDocusignCondController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Opportunity getOpportunityDetails(String recordId){
        Opportunity objOpportunity = [SELECT id,Group_HR_Name__c,Group_HR_Email__c,Group_Type__c FROM Opportunity WHERE id =:recordId ];
        String message = 'Hi'+objOpportunity.Group_HR_Name__c+'\nPlease DocuSign the Producer Compensation Disclosure Notice.pdf,\nThank You, IU Health Plans';            
           
        dfsle.Recipient myEmployer = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(objOpportunity.Group_HR_Name__c, objOpportunity.Group_HR_Email__c, null,'Employer',new dfsle.Entity(objOpportunity.id));
        dfsle.UUID myTemplateId = dfsle.UUID.parse(SYSTEM.Label.VTY_Docusign_Commission_Template);
        dfsle.Document templateDocument = dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(myTemplateId,'Procedure Comission Employee Notification');
        List<dfsle.Document> allDocumentList = new List<dfsle.Document>();
         if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
             allDocumentList.add(templateDocument); 
             dfsle.CustomField myCustomField1 = new dfsle.CustomField('text','##SFOpportunity', objOpportunity.id, null, true, true);
             dfsle.Envelope myEnvel = new dfsle.Envelope(null,null,null,null,new List<dfsle.Document> {templateDocument},null,null,null,'Please DocuSign: Producer Compensation Disclosure Notice.pdf',message,null,null);
             myEnvel = myEnvel.withCustomFields(new List<dfsle.CustomField> { myCustomField1 });
             myEnvel = myEnvel.withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { myEmployer });
             myEnvel = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(myEnvel,true);
                          
         }         
        return objOpportunity;
    }
}
```

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has an out of the box feature that does this for you automatically without code: https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Adding-Completed-Documents-to-the-Notes-and-Attachments-New